# Getting true/false from SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to determine whether a customer has bought 100 or more unique drinks using a SQL query and so far I've done:

```
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT beer_id)
     FROM Orders
     WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com'
```

How would I test whether the result of this is 100 or more?

Update: Sorry for the vague question, I need to use standard SQL.

Comment: Are you doing this in SQL alone, (if yes, what is the RDBMS? MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, PortreSQL?) or in any framework like PHP, etc?

Comment: what do you want? do you want the count of unique drinks, or a true/false evaluation of whether or not they have ordered more than 100.

Comment: please can you offer an expected output? that will help a lot. Thanks

Comment: The output would just be true/false, and I need to use standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in MySQL, not sure about others:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT beer_id) > 100
 FROM Orders
 WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com'
```

Just put a boolean condition in the `SELECT`. It will evaluate to 0 for false or 1 for true.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `having` clause as in:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT beer_id)
FROM Orders
WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com'
having count(distinct beer_id) > 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE` with a sub-query which produces a single row:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT beer_id)
                 FROM Orders
                 WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com') > 100 
                 THEN 'More than 100' ELSE 'Not more than 100' END As ColumnName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(beer_id)
     FROM Orders
     WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com'
group by beer_id
having COUNT(beer_id) > 100
```

Comment: This is not answering the question

Comment: @Brewal can you explain me why?

Comment: Take a look at the title :]

Comment: Yes, I see @Brewal and you're right, is he looking for a boolean result?

Comment: Indeed, but the question is unclear. With your code you will get no result if the count is lower than 100 ; which is not (as I understood the question) what he wants

Comment: @Brewal No, it is not, i think what he is looking for is Tim Schmelter answer

Answer (score 1):

or one more :

```
select case when (count(distinct beer_id)>100) then 1
        else 0 end
    from orders where patron_email='.....'
```

Comment: huh? how do you even know their is a firstName field

Comment: I'd forgotten to change the sql after trying it first - oops.  you were all pretty quick with the downvotes mind - it only took a fwew seconds to change it

Comment: please justify any downvotes - especially as this solution works :(

Comment: The downvotes came because it looked like the answer had nothing to do with the question. I reversed mine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming T-SQL

```
DECLARE @result AS INT
DECLARE @boolean AS INT

SET @result = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT beer_id)
                FROM Orders
                WHERE patron_email='smith@gmail.com')

IF @result > 100
    BEGIN
        SET @boolean = 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @boolean = 0
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` operator yields a boolean:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 12345
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(beer_id) > 100
    ) AS at_least_one_customer_ordered_100_different_beers
    ;
```